# Altruism in viscous (asexual) populations

Tags: evolution, mathematical-models, population-genetics, sociality, evolutionary-game-theory

The viscosity of a population is the tendency of offspring to remain
near their place of birth. Taylor 1992 ("Altruism in viscous populations") provides a model to study how viscosity affects the evolution of altruism in a patch-structured population. In Taylor's model, the marginal inclusive fitness is given by
\begin{equation}
  W = bR -c - s^{2}(b-c)R
\end{equation}
where $R$ is the relatedness of a mother to random offspring born on her breeding patch and $s$ is the probability the offspring will remain on the natal patch. The altruistic act creates $b$ offspring with average relatedness $R$ and $-c$ offspring with relatedness 1.

My question is about the term $s^{2}(b-c)R$. Taylor explains this term as follows:

> these b - c extra offspring remain on the natal patch with probability
>   s and will therefore displace s(b - c) random individuals competing
>   for the next generation breeding spots on that patch, and these will
>   be native to that patch with probability s and in this case will have
>   average relatedness R to the actor. Thus these displaced individuals
>   will have average relatedness sR (p. 353)

**My question is:** Why is the average relatedness $sR$ (as opposed to $R$)? In other words, why is the term that accounts for competition among relatives $s^2(b-c)R$---as opposed to $s(b-c)R$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $sR$ that your looking at is the average relatedness of the *next generation*.  This assumes that the new immigrants into the the population are completely unrelated. So if the population is completely viscous ($s=1$) the average relatedness of the next generation equals that of the current generation.  On the other hand, if the population is not viscous ($s=0$) the next generation would be entirely unrelated because it would only be made up of unrelated immigrants.

The $s(b-c)$ is the number if individuals that are displaced by new offspring.  Again if all of the new generation sticks around ($s=1$) then the number of displaced individuals equals the number of new individuals.  And if all new progeny leave ($s=0$), there are no displaced individuals.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Adam C. Now I understand that the relatedness after migration has to be a fraction of $R$. But why $sR$ exactly and not, say, $s^2R$ or any other fraction of $R$?

Comment: It is specifically $s$ and not some fraction or multiple of $s$ because the model assumes all incoming migrants are entirely unrelated ($R=0$).  

For example, if $s=0.5$ and $R=1$, half of the population leaves and is replaced by incoming migrants in the next generation and all that remain are perfectly related.  So, in the following generation, 50% of population has an average relatedness of $R=1$ (those that stayed) and 50% of population has an average relatedness of $R=0$ (those that just arrived). Therefore the average relatedness for the entire population is $sR$ or $0.5$.